# How to store lines in a file as latest at top in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have lines that can store logs of my script in a separate file and it working perfectly but their is an issue it stores latest at bottom of a file which is a default behavior of Linux what I want is that it redirect output to a logs file as latest at the top.
Here are the lines which i include at the top of my Hooks_script and these lines store output of every command written below these lines in a separate logs file

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>/tmp/git_hooks_logs.log 2>&1
#create logs of every command written below these lines
```

Comment: Doing that would be extremely inefficient (requires re-writing the whole file every time a line is added). You should rather look at processing the log file from "bottom" to "top".

Comment: How it would be done. Will you please elaborate

Comment: There is a program `tac` which is reverse if `cat`

Comment: I don't want to read it in terminal, i want it to store in log file in backward order

Comment: Due to the way how files are handled in current operating systems this is just not possible without rewriting the whole file. Reorganize your process so it respects the limitations;) You can keep another copy of your log, which will be reverse sorted (using `tac` each time after you add a line).

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus is there is no reliable way to do this in a single operation, and several ways to do it with more than a single operation, some of which can be enetered on one line if that is important to you.
You might want to look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/

Comment: Alternatively write the log in forward order and provide a log reader which allows users to view it in last-first order. You could write a simple csv flie and people could view it in excel.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Possible, that is, to write a CSV file? Sure, I've done that on numerous occasions. Here's an excerpt (with not much data filled in):
`entrydate,lastname,firstname,middlename,spfirstname,splastname,spmiddlename,apt,streetaddr,city,region,zip,email,ext,phonenum,phhrs,phonenum2,phhrs2,phonenum3,phhrs3,area,phonex,phone,area2,phonex2,phone2,area3,phone3,phonex3


"20140125","  ","The Natural Healing Center","","","","","","","","","","","","734-973-8290","","","","","","734","973","8290","","","","","",""`

Comment: Sorry, can't get a newline between phonex3 AND "20140125"